# How to consume a SOAP Webservice in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am new to Mule and need your help to consume it. I have a 3rd party SOAP service which takes one input and provides one output as mention below. How can I call it from MULE, it is a passthrough proxy so need transformation is required. just need to call it from Mule.

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="http://test.co.nz/controlkeysdetails">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:getControlKeyDetail xmlns:con="http://test.co.nz/controlkeysdetails">
         <con:keyCode>M2M_IN_PRODUCT_CODE</con:keyCode>
      </con:getControlKeyDetail>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ControlKeyDetailResponse xmlns="http://test.co.nz/controlkeysdetails"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Mule Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" service="DSS_ControlKeyDetailsProxy" port="DSS_ControlKeyDetailsProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint" serviceAddress="http://esb1.test.2degreesmobile.co.nz:8280/services/DSS_ControlKeyDetailsProxy.DSS_ControlKeyDetailsProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint" wsdlLocation="http://hnzclakl194:8280/services/DSS_ControlKeyDetailsProxy?wsdl" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <flow name="soapwebserviceFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="{'con:keyCode':'M2M_IN_PRODUCT_CODE'}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="getControlKeyDetail" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks for your reply Anirban. I have updated the code but getting "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM" error. I am not sure how to set Payload

Answer (score 0):

1.Put the request **before** **`<ws:consumer/>`** may be in set payload component:-

```
 <con:getControlKeyDetail xmlns:con="http://test.co.nz/controlkeysdetails">
   <con:keyCode>M2M_IN_PRODUCT_CODE</con:keyCode>
</con:getControlKeyDetail>
```

2. Remove `<echo-component/>` after `<ws:consumer/>` and replace it with `<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer/>` something like following :-

```
 <flow name="soapwebserviceFlow">
  <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
  <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="getControlKeyDetail" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
  <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
</flow>
```